# add same value to range of cells in microsoft excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, spreadsheet

I want to add the same word from cell B1 to B40000

I do not want to use the click and drag box method to apply it across multiple cells/rows.

I know I have to type in the formula bar B1:B40000 but I am missing something.

Comment: Any reason click and drag wouldn't work? If you don't want to do a lot of scrolling just start the drag, hitting <kbd>End</kbd> and letting go.

Comment: Have you tried copying the contents of cell `B1`, selecting cells `B2` to `B40000`, and then choosing paste?

Comment: Any luck with this in the end Brad?

Comment: I did Go To: and typed in the range: B1:B4000, it selected (highlighted that range) then I clicked Ctrl-V to paste in the same value into every cell that was selected. That did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the box in the top left corner, the one that shows the cell reference currently selected. Enter B40000 in here and press enter. This will take you straight to that cell.

[image: Cell ref]

Next enter the word you want in that cell, then with the cell selected hold Ctrl+Shift and press up on the arrow keys. This will add all cells in that column before B40000 to your selection.

Finally go to the Fill function, usually on the first page if you have the Ribbon, click on Series and then select Columns and AutoFill.

[image: Fill]

This will fill in the all of the selected cells with the same value.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to create a so-called "cell reference" : just click B40000 and print the "=B1" in the formula bar (http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-or-change-a-cell-reference-HA102749036.aspx#BMcreate_a_cell_reference_on_the_same_w)

Comment: that adds one value to one cell. I need to add the same value across the range of B2:B4000, so B2, B3, B4....B4000 need all the same value